# Is it possible to pass parameters to ui-router within a PHP redirect?

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was wondering if it is possible to pass parameters to ui-router via a PHP redirect?

For example, I have the following state:

```
    // Registration
    .state('registration', {
        url: '/registration/:valid', 
        templateUrl: '../partials/register/registration.php',
        controller: 'RegistrationController', 
        controllerAs: 'Registration', 
        params: {
            valid: null
        },
        authenticate: false, 
        data: {
            authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
        }
    })
```

I am trying to pass a parameter via a PHP redirect like so:

```
// Return success
header( 'Location: http://<...>/registration?valid=true' ); /* Redirect browser */
```

But it doesn't seem to pick it up.  I always get the default value of `valid`

Then in my controller:

```
var self = this;
self.valid = $state.params.valid;
```

But I always get the value of 'undefined' (default value).
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are defining your parameter in state `url`

```
url: '/registration/:valid'
```

then you don't need to specify it in query string just pass its value. like this:

```
header( 'Location: http://<...>/registration/true');
```

Otherwise remove parameter from url and just define it in params object.

```
.state('registration', {
    url: '/registration/', 
    templateUrl: '../partials/register/registration.php',
    params: {
        valid: null
    },
```

And use your original syntax in php like this

```
// Return success
header( 'Location: http://<...>/registration?valid=true' );
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I actually had two other errors with my code (invalid URL and a secondary URL that was executing that I wasn't aware of).  However, your first example (also suggested from @pablorsk) worked for me once I had corrected my other mistakes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Change PHP**

```
// Return success
header( 'Location: http://<...>/registration/true');
```

**Catch ?parameter from URL**

```
let params = $location.search('valid');
if (params.valid) {
    // do something
}
```

Regards!

Comment: I had already tried your first option but to no success.  It just seems to redirect to the `.otherwise` state.  With your second option, how can I catch the ?parameter within the `.state`?